# Does "Stop the task" kill an EXE that launched successfully?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

In Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 6.1 (build 7601 SP1), in Scheduled Tasks, I have a "Start a program" task that launches a normal EXE (visible desktop application) at login. This app is intended to run for the entire session. On the Settings tab there is a box (apparently ticked by default): "Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days".

If I tick this, does it mean my app will be forcibly killed after 3 days, even if it is responsive and working? Or does it only relate to the initial time the application takes to start up? The docs at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722178(v=ws.11).aspx do not make this entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The task scheduler keeps track of its launched processes and kills them if told so.

Comment: By `kill` do you mean it does `taskkill /f /im executablename.exe` ?

Comment: The task scheduler sends a normal terminate signal to the process (like `taskkill` without `/f`) unless you check the box for forcing the termination (then it's like `taskkill /f`).

Comment: By Forcing do you mean ungraceful/immediatte termination?

Comment: That's the Settings option "If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop".